# Can I write custom task start/end records to VSTS build/release log

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to be able to add items to the logs displayed during VSTS builds and releases:
[image: Log entries]

I've looked at [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) and written the following test powershell script

```
$guid = $env:taskGuid
write-host "##vso[task.logdetail id=$guid;name=project1;type=build;order=1]create new timeline record"

# write-host "##vso[task.logdetail id=new guid;parentid=exist timeline record guid;name=project1;type=build;order=1]create new nested timeline record"

write-host "##vso[task.logdetail id=$guid;progress=50;state=InProgress;]update timeline record"
write-host "##vso[task.logdetail id=$guid;state=Completed;result=Succeeded]complete timeline record"
```

I was hoping to see additional entries in the log but I see no difference at all, not even the `write-host` statements appearing.

[image]

So I have 2 questions

1. What should I see from my sample script above?
2. Is it possible to get
   additional entries in that log shown in the initial screenshot
   without actually adding additional tasks?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you're using is designed to show in the timeline which doesn't appear to be used in the new build layout yet (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/project/navigation/preview-features?view=vsts&tabs=previous-nav) to disable preview of new build output). If you use the old build output, select the step for the powershell script you're executing and then select time line, you will then see your step (which in my case is ssloan) being logged by the logger. [image: vstsimage]. See [here](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/12/13/vsts-powershell-commands/) for a better run down of the various build steps than I could give.

For just outputting the the logs you can use a variety of writers provided in [PowerShell utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/?view=powershell-6) Write-Host should be sufficient so long as you always have a host to write to. These will then appear in your logs

Comment: THanks - that makes a bit more sense with the old view of timeline. Can I call a task group from within a script?

Comment: [Task groups are an encapsulation of a sequence of task in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts). The same way you can't call a VSTS build task from a script you can't call a task group from within a script.  You can utilise task groups in both the build and release pipelines in VSTS.

Comment: That's what I thought. The reason I want to is that I'm trying to loop through a set of tasks - I know I can use the multi configuration option to do this, but that's not available for deployment groups. Ie I need to loop through these tasks on several servers. So I just wondered if I could call tasks from within my script loop to make the logging output clearer.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help with looping tasks I'm afraid. My only comment would be to handle what the tasks are doing in code to enable you to handle the looping with your own logic. Sorry about that!