# Where did the Build Timeline tab go in Azure DevOps Server?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We upgraded our TFS 2018 instance to Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.

In a few of our scripts we are creating timeline entries to log the process and see more detailed results in the build summary.

The main logs overview page still shows the Build steps and the time it took, but clicking on the build step for more details now only shows the log. I am no longer seeing the Timeline tab on the build step.

To be clear, we use the task.logdetail to submit the information to TFS, such as:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logdetail id=$($guid);name=$($projectKey);type=build;order=$i;state=Initialized;]"
```

I see its still documented on docs, but how do we access the information, is it now only available through the API?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#task-commands

Comment: Are you talking about  `2019-10-04T09:54:05.1025080Z ##[command]git lfs version` this `2019-10-04T09:54:05.1025080Z ` info in previous log are missing in new build log view?

Comment: No, what i mean is that the timeline records created by the powershell script are no longer visible in the UI of TFS 2019. These were available in 2018 in the build results, each Build task had a Timeline tab to show the timelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you should talked about timeline tab for each build task.

[image]

This is due to from Azure DevOps Server 2019, we started to use the [New build results page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/jun-19-vsts#new-build-results-page) in web portal UI to track the build result.

[image]

As you can see this syntax you're using is designed to show in the timeline which doesn't appear to be used in the new build layout yet.

Take a look at this similar question here: [Can I write custom task start/end records to VSTS build/release log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611259/can-i-write-custom-task-start-end-records-to-vsts-build-release-log)

Besides, you could also submit a feature request for new build result page [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21),our PM will kindly review it.